# Passing function as parameter, tuple or function with two arguements

Tags: scala

I've been tasked with implementing this function, that should return true or false whether or not an input array was sorted

```
def isSorted[A] (as: Array[A], ordered: (A,A) => Boolean): Boolean = ???
```

Not I am a bit confused about the `(A,A)` it looks like the "ordered" variable is of the tuple type, but it also looks like a function with two parameters. Which one of the two is it?

Comment: A function of two arguments which should answer if the first element should be before of the second one

Comment: nice, i'm a bit uncertain about whether im supposed to write implementations of this functions, or how that works?

Comment: So the idea is simple, you use that function to determine the order. So suppose you pass an array of ints and you want to check if it is ordered ascending, you pass a function like this `(x, y) => x <= y` now imagine you pass a array of users and you want to check if it ordered according to the users' age an in descending order, you would pass a function like this: `(u1, u2) => u1.age >= u2.age` - so you do not need to implement it for implementing `isSorted` you use it for implementing `isSorted` and the final user of `isSorted` is the one that pass that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a function of two arguments. A function of a single tuple argument is written `((A, A)) => Boolean`

Functions of a single argument can usually be written without parens around the argument type, but this is ambiguous as you have noticed. The ambiguity is resolved in favour of a binary function type, and you can avoid the ambiguity with an additional set of parens.